# Laravel html & Form

Tags: laravel

В Laravel раньше был официальный пакет Html & Forms и не так давно его убрали. Вид примерно был такой:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar']) !!}
    //
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Наткнулся на сторонний сайт где продолжают поддерживают данный пакет laravelcollective.com ...

Разработчики Laravel так нигде и не объяснили причину удаления данного пакета.

*Вопрос*: есть ли какая-нибудь уязвимость в данных формах и стоит ли их продолжать использовать?

Comment: Причина удаления, чтобы фраймворк был "легче" [прочитать тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35696207)

Comment: Этот пакет ставился и устанавливался отдельно от основного фреймворка и никак не влиял на вес

Comment: _core components_ не требуют отдельной установки. Этот компонент был удален из _кора_, так что сейчас он устанавливается отдельно.